# Higher resolution on Macbook air - simulated?

Tags: screen, resolution, macbook-pro

When I connect my MBA to Apple TV it adjusts the MBA resolution to something else which makes everything smaller but gives me more screen real-estate. I don't want to do this often but sometimes its nice when an app window is large and not scalable.
Is there a way to do this without connecting to ATV?
Preferably a script to run that makes the adjustment and then one to set it back?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

SwitchResX provides functionality for this.
When you have installed it, open it from System Preferences, go to the Color LCD tab at the side, and go to the second tab (I believe). From there you should be able to set 1920x1080 without being connected to your TV.